# Powerpoint VBA: Loop to make textboxes visible gets issues when adding bring to front

Tags: vba, loops, powerpoint

So I have written the following code to make the textboxes in my presentation visisible and then bring them to the front (they are made invisible by a separate macro):

```
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim oPPT As Presentation

For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes

If oShp.Type = msoTextBox Then
        oShp.Visible = True
        oShp.ZOrder msoBringToFront
End If

Next oShp
Next oSld
```

It worked perfectly before I added the bring to front command! Now only around half of the shapes are made visible when the code is run. I've been reading around online and it appears that ZOrder changes the number of shapes and that is why only some are made visible.... but cannot work out a way around it! Would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help @SteveRindsberg, a couple a tweaks to your code and i cracked it :)

```
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim aShapeArray() 
Dim x As Long


For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
x = 1
If oSld.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
ReDim aShapeArray(1 To oSld.Shapes.Count)

' Build an array of shapes
For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
  Set aShapeArray(x) = oShp
  x = x + 1
Next


' Then do what you need to do with each shape in the array
For x = 1 To UBound(aShapeArray)
Set oShp = aShapeArray(x)
      If oShp.Type = msoTextBox Then
        oShp.Visible = True
        oShp.ZOrder msoBringToFront
      End If
Next
End If

Next
```

Comment: Just a teenie-tiny correction: the shape type can be TextBox or PlaceHolder. I changed the code example accordingly.

Comment: feeelix's code contains a tiny bug. The line that tests the type of the Shape object should also let msoPlaceholder shapes pass.

Answer (score 0):

You've put your finger on the cause.  The For Each/Next loop appears to take a snapshot of the shape order at the time it starts.  If you change the shape order or delete shapes in the body of the loop it throws things off.  Instead, try something like the (untested)(air)code below to build an array of references to the shapes and then process them one at a time from the array:

```
Dim aShapeArray() as Shape
Dim x as Long
ReDim aShapeArray(1 to oSld.Shapes.Count) as Shape

' Build an array of shapes
For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
  Set aShapeArray(x) = oShp
  x = x+1
Next

' Then do what you need to do with each shape in the array
For x = 1 to Ubound(aShapeArray)
Set oShp = aShapeArray(x)
If oShp.Type = msoTextBox Then
        oShp.Visible = True
        oShp.ZOrder msoBringToFront
End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the suggestion! I have tried it out but it highlights .Count  comes up with a compile error: constant expression required. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: See edited version; now creates a dynamic array then redims that as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! i managed to tweak a couple of bits and get it working!